# adb: device not found

Tags: android, python, adb, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to build a Kivy app on my Android phone using Buildozer. But adb is not finding my device. This is the error I am getting:

```
dan@dan-asus:~/kivy$ adb usb
error: device not found
dan@dan-asus:~/kivy$ adb devices
List of devices attached
```

I've added my vendor and product id that I got from `lsusb` in my `/lib/udev/rules.d/70-android-tools-adb.rules` file as so:

```
# Lenovo A789
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="17ef", ATTR{idProduct}=="7497", MODE="0666", OWNER="dan", TAG+="uaccess"
```

Have two 1.1 and two 2.0 USB outlets. Tried all four of them. Made sure I restarted adb every time I made a change and even tried to reboot my phone a few time.

What am I missing?

adb version is 1.0.31

Comment: Did you try adb kill-server then adb start-server?

Comment: Yep. That's what I meant by "restarted adb".

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/09/the-most-comprehensive-write-up-on-how.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation for that... so here is my "answer".

I can think of a couple of things that you don't mention specifically in your question:

1. Do you have a file `~/.android/adb_usb.ini`? If yes, is the vendor ID written there? (in your case should be `0x17EF` in a single line). Try with that and restart your ADB server.
2. Is ADB enabled in your device? You can check that with `lsusb -v -d 17ef:7497 | grep -B 3 -i iInterface` and look for some interface with class 255, subclass 66, protocol 1. That's your ADB USB interface in the device, if you don't find it, check the device's settings/configuration.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't have that file. I saw other people recommending that as well. Got it working at my job computer, so this is not really an issue for me atm. I'll try to check it when I get home.

Comment: btw, Google finally came to their senses and removed VendorID whitelist check in the latest version of `adb` - so there is no need for the `adb_usb.ini` any more. Anyway even before they did - `0x17EF` (Lenovo) was on that list - so that was unlikely the reason in this case